# We begin with an S

Tags: word, pattern

I recently saw a puzzle that I really enjoyed, and wanted to try my hand at something with a similar idea. Feedback is appreciated!

> S _ _ _ _: long, flat places for science (5)
>
> S _ _ _ _: quavered with a hand replacement (3)
>
> S _ _ _ _ _: beneath a split (2)
>
> S _ _ _ _: heated hive members (4)
>
> S _ _ _ _ _: frequently ease up (2)
>
> S _ _ _ _ _: slashes cleaning cloths (4)
>
> S _ _ _ _: concern that terrifies (5)
>
> S _ _ _ _ _ _ _: waiting for a transaction (4)
>
> S _ _ _ _ _: exchanged cackler (3)
>
> S _ _ _: final delivery (3)
>
> S _ _ _ _ _ _ _: yammer that follows unnoticed (8)
>
> **Answer: _ _ _ _ _**

Comment: Are the numbers enumeration? If so, the dashes and the numbers don't always match..

Comment: Yes, but not in the specific way you're thinking.

Comment: This is a great first puzzle! Welcome to puzzling

Comment: Very enjoyable!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The final answer is

> START

Each of the clues

> contains clues for two words, one starting with S and one without it.

long, flat places for science (5)

> SLABS

quavered with a hand replacement (3)

> SHOOK

beneath a split (2)

> SUNDER

heated hive members (4)

> SWARM

frequently ease up (2)

> SOFTEN

slashes cleaning cloths (4)

> SWIPES (thanks to Dr Xorile)

concern that terrifies (5)

> SCARE

waiting for a transaction (4)

> SPENDING

exchanged cackler (3)

> SWITCH

final delivery (3)

> SEND

yammer that follows unnoticed (8)

> STALKING

I think the numbers are

> indices into the answers

which gives us

> SOUR OPENING

Solving in the same way, we get

> START

Comment: Great job! You're in the final stretch. :)

Comment: Swipes is presumably the one you're missing

Comment: Which makes sour opening?

Comment: Very clever puzzle, and very well done solving it

Comment: I don't get a single thing from both the answer and the question. If each clue gives us two words (as in the second spoiler) why are there only one word per clue (as in SLABS, SHOOK, etc.)? Furthermore, what's the connection between 'sour opening' and 'start'? Apologies for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @WilliamNathanael the clues give two words: one word which is the word given, one word which is the word minus the s (e.g waiting for = PENDING, transaction = SPENDING). For the final word, SOUR = TART and OPENING = START

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Ohh wow!! That is extremely amazing. This kind of puzzle makes P.SE a neverending fun source of puzzles. Keep it up, Red Octopus! We're waiting for your next!

Comment: Again, I have to admit it was derived from something I saw a little while ago, but I'm glad you guys enjoyed it! I'm still not sure if it's too gimmicky to try again with another letter, or if I should move on to another idea--any opinions?

Comment: @RedOctopus I thought it was fun.  I wouldn't mind seeing more like it.  So long as you explain the mechanic at the start, it shouldn't be too gimmicky.